# pycharm terminal como se puede poner el símbolo ~

Tags: terminal, pycharm

Estoy empleado el terminal de pycharm para introducir comandos de git y, por algún motivo no me deja escribir el símbolo **~** ,lo necesito para poner ~HEAD ,se hace con (alt gr) +4. Lo he probado con otros editores y si me funciona, pero por algún motivo no me funciona en el IDE, no sé si será algo de la configuración, que he tocado, o si por el contrario es algo así en los editores de Jetbrain.
En el segundo caso ¿cómo se puede solucionar?

Comment: Lo usas muy frecuente? Te recomiendo usar powershell dentro de cmd. Y también comprueba si puedes introducir el carácter ese dentro de pycharm, no solo en la terminal, en su barra de búsqueda en el editor de código etc.

Comment: Si tienes un teclado con "Ñ", generalmente también puedes sacar el "~" con (alt gr) + ñ